# Is it required to form::open() tag in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm a little bit confused about Forms. Is `Form::open()` required to send it in controller? And I don't want to load it so I used AJAX.

View:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'register', 'id' => 'register']) !!}
   {!! Form::label('FirstName: ') !!} {!! Form::text('firstname', null, ['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}
   {!! Form::submit() !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

JS:

```
$('#register').on('submit', function(){

    $.post('/register',{
        data: {req: $(this).serialize()}
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form submits because you are not preventing the default event via ajax. Your ajax should look like thos

```
    $('#register').on('submit', function(e){

    $.post('/register',{
        data: {req: $(this).serialize()}
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
    event.preventDefault();

 });
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Ahh. I see. Thanks for that. How could I forget that.

Comment: @aldrin27 It happens to the best of us. Glad I could help, and thanks for accepting my answer. Happy coding.

Comment: No prob bro. I thought there's something wrong with my code. LOL